# Simulating a low-bandwidth, high-latency network connection on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, traffic-shaping

I'd like to simulate a high-latency, low-bandwidth network connection on my Linux machine.

Limiting bandwidth has been discussed before, e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/66574/how-to-throttle-bandwidth-on-a-linux-network-interface), but I can't find any posts which address limiting both bandwidth and latency.

I can get either high latency or low bandwidth using `tc`.  But I haven't been able to combine these into a single connection.  In particular, the example rate control script [here](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) doesn't work for me:

```
# tc qdisc add dev lo root handle 1:0 netem delay 100ms 
# tc qdisc add dev lo parent 1:1 handle 10: tbf rate 256kbit buffer 1600 limit 3000
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

How can I create a low-bandwidth, high-latency connection, using `tc` or any other readily-available tool?

Comment: have you tried combining approaches from your links, eg. use tc for latency and trickle for bandwidth? (It's uglier than just using tc, but might still work;)

Comment: That's a good idea (and, indeed, trickle will even add latency), but unfortunately Firefox doesn't load under trickle, and that's what I need to test.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Aha!  It works if we reverse the order of the commands.

```
tc qdisc add dev lo root handle 1: htb default 12 
tc class add dev lo parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 20kbps ceil 20kbps 
tc qdisc add dev lo parent 1:12 netem delay 1000ms
```

https://lists.linux-foundation.org/pipermail/netem/2010-May/001388.html

Comment: Anyone interested as to why, it seems that the netem qdisc cannot be a parent, so you have to rearrange the hierarchy to have it as a leaf node.

Comment: Note that the bandwidth limit is in one direction only (outgoing).  You have to do additional work to make it happen in both directions (apparently using ifb).  http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem#Emulating_wide_area_network_delays

Comment: Came across this when trying to grok tc. From what I've read the first line creates 1:0, but the second line refers to 1:1? (probably my understanding which is wrong - but I've peered at lots of pages trying to understand how classes/qtdiscs are numbered)

Answer (score 1):

It's not free, but the Charles Web Debugging Proxy can simulate low bandwidth high latency connections

http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/throttling/

Comment: Interestingly enough, I'm actually doing this for web debugging.  But surely there must be a way to do this without spending money.  :)

Comment: Sadly Charles doesn't seem to work with local traffic.  It dies when I try to access 192.168.1.1 through the proxy.

Comment: Or just use WANEm, for free: http://wanem.sourceforge.net/