# How to deliberately introduce a delay for incoming UDP packets

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, udp, traffic-shaping

I want each packet (that match iptables rule) to be delayed by some fixed time interval. How to to this?

Preudocode: `iptables -A INPUT -p udp <more conditions> -j DELAY --delay 50000 # delay UDP packets for 50 milliseconds`

**Update:** @related [Simulating a low-bandwidth, high-latency network connection on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/147156/simulating-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-network-connection-on-linux)

Comment: Why?  Testing purposes?

Comment: Yes, testing/debugging. Actually `tc qdisc add dev eth1 root netem delay 250ms` helped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tc qdisc add dev eth1 root netem delay 250ms` hack allows to do it globally for the given interface. It includes UDP packets.

It delays outgoing packets only although. For incoming packets you can route packets though a virtual router (created by separate network namespace and `veth` with `netem` attached to veth side of link).