# Artificial network delay tcp/udp (bigger ping) for defined application? (windows)

Tags: windows, networking, ping, tcp, udp

I have a game where people can easy detect who i am looking at my ping, i want to make my ping highter.
How can i set network delay for all network connections for defined application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating a low-bandwidth, high-latency network connection on Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/147156/simulating-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-network-connection-on-linux) also perhaps check out [How to deliberately introduce a delay for incoming UDP packets](http://superuser.com/questions/173751/how-to-deliberately-introduce-a-delay-for-incoming-udp-packets?rq=1)

Comment: @techie007 sorry, i added tag "windows" to prevent misunderstood next time. And introduce a delay for _incoming_ udp packets isn't what i exactly need, better to set delay for outcoming packets. But thanks for delay in iptables, maybe usefull.

Comment: Ahh, I see you did have it in the title, but I kept looking at the tags. :/  So not direct dupes, sorry 'bout that, but hopefully they'll be helpful you you/someone for coming up with a solution. :)