# How to intentionally delay TCP packets in one direction

Tags: windows, networking, tcp

I've looked at this already: [How to deliberately introduce a delay for incoming UDP packets](https://superuser.com/questions/173751/how-to-deliberately-introduce-a-delay-for-incoming-udp-packets?rq=1)

I am testing a server-client system, and need to delay messages from the server to the client by some specified delay -- say 1ms. I don't want packets in the other direction to be delayed.

Some sort of proxy software is completely acceptable. Any suggestions for windows?

Comment: Are you using HTTP/S? The tool [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) functions as a SOCKS proxy and will allow you to slow down or otherwise manipulate HTTP requests for testing purposes.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Straight sockets, as far as I can tell. I didn't write the server or client. Just testing  what happens with two clients receive events at "noticeably" different times.

Answer (score 3):

WANem (http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) is a liveCD linux distro that let's you manipulate traffic on the wire.  You can limit bandwidth, introduce lag, jitter, lost packets, and a bunch of other cool things.

Just boot it in a spare PC or VM and create routes on your client and server and you're all set.