# netem for Mac OS X to emulate network latency and dropped packets

Tags: linux, macos, networking, performance, emulation

I'm looking for an open source/free network emulator tool that I could use on Mac OS X, to simulate a slow network connection, limited bandwidth and other network characteristics such as dropped packets etc for both UDP/TCP connections (or even on the physical layer).

I'm looking for the simplest solution that would allow me to run TCP/UDP servers and have a few clients connect to them on localhost emulating various network connections.

I'm mainly wondering if I can use something like Linux's `netem` on Mac OS X (or even better cross-platform Windows/Linux/Mac).

Perhaps I can run VirtualBox and a Linux kernel running `netem`, has anyone had luck with that?

Related: [Simulating a low-bandwidth, high-latency network connection on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/147156/simulating-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-network-connection-on-linux)

Answer (score 11):

The developer tools in 10.7 come with a prefPane for emulating a limited network connection:

[image]

Via [Network Link Conditioner in Lion » Matt Legend Gemmell](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/07/25/network-link-conditioner-in-lion)

Comment: This does not seem to work for localhost / 127.0.0.1 connections.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ns-2](http://nsnam.isi.edu/nsnam/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_ns-2):

> Ns-2 is a discrete event simulator targeted at networking research.
>   Ns-2 provides substantial support for simulation of TCP, routing, and
>   multicast protocols over wired and wireless (local and satellite)
>   networks.
>
> **Installing NS2 on a MacOS X / Intel Based**
>
> I've tried to install ns2-allinone-2.29.3/.2 onto an intel mac based
>   system. After some problems during the compile phase, the simulator
>   part (ns) seems to be fully working. Nam, instead, got some strange
>   errors, related to Xlib. In my knowledge, this strange behaviour is
>   related to some changes to api part of Xlib into macos/intel version.
>   Attached is the error, that i've when try to run nam onto my mac intel
>   based.
>
> ```
> tengu:~/Desktop/ns-allinone-2.29/nam-1.11 valvoline$ ./nam 
> Xlib: sequence lost (0x10006 > 0x9) in reply type 0x0!
> X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  1 (X_CreateWindow)
>   Resource id in failed request:  0xa
>   Serial number of failed request:  6
>   Current serial number in output stream:  9
> ```

You can go [here for a full blown tutorial](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/index.html) on Ns-2.

Comment: Please add details as to how ns-2 answers the question - the linked cannot be relied upon to remain over time.

Comment: haven't tested it, but I notice that there's an updated build at the page you've linked..