# Bandwidth Sharing 2 pcs ( linux and windows )

Tags: bandwidth

Greeting All

How can we share bandwidth between 2 pcs ( a windows pc and a linux pc ). We have one adsl connection. We would like the users to share bandwidth when both are active and when only one is active then he can get all the bandwidth.

Our router settings look like this:

[image]

**Note: Qos Type supports :UBR, CBR, VBR**

Comment: What do you want to achieve? At the moment, this router will assign traffic as required. If you want to do something like network load-balancing, your router is not up to the task with its current OS.

Comment: @Randolph West so how can I easily establish something like this. I share my internet connection with my brother. I need to set up a small crawling system on my pc but don't want to eat all the bandwidth to not give my brother a headache.

Comment: What crawling system? Perhaps it has a bandwidth shaper in its configuration.

Comment: see this question: http://superuser.com/q/66574/33303