# Ubuntu 13.10 - make eth0 or wan0 interface upload/download into slow motion for testing software

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, performance

I have a software where i need to test by making some low speed internet, very limited upload/download, after some time auto disconnect and reconnect such scenarios.

I have found that i can try wanem or wanembridge but they are not helping me because its like a router.

i need to make the Ubuntu 13.10 eth0 and wlan0 slow motion cause i have many other dependencies based on Ubuntu 13.10.

Any idea how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [netem] emulator (http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem)
Also look at the man page from the below link (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man8/tc-netem.8.html)

Comment: This is also a quick tool helped me: http://superuser.com/questions/66574/how-to-throttle-bandwidth-on-a-linux-network-interface

Answer (score 2):

```
$ apt-get install wondershaper
```

This limits the download limit to 1000 kilobits and uplaod to 200 kilobits.

```
$ wondershaper eth0 1000 200
```

this removes the limitation back to normal

```
$ wondershaper clear eth0
```

this can be also inclued in the network interfaces to have default when interface is UP do that when its down clear it

```
$ /etc/network/interfaces
up /sbin/wondershaper eth0 downspeed upspeed
down /sbin/wondershaper clear eth1
```